# How do I deal with testing "copied" files in tests?

Tags: file, travis-ci

I don't really want to mock out a whole stack of calls for the test - I'm much happier (and confident) if I can test the full end result in a particular test case, which ends up copying some files.

How do I check or setup the copied files on Travis? I can't seem to find any information regarding build/test artifacts.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive regarding the files? You can copy files using bash "cp" commang in your travis setup, e.g. to your $HOME/tests dir. 

In your scripts you can use php exec etc.

What would you like to accomplish? Compare files, send to external source... etc.

Comment: Just wanting to copy files from one location to another on the hard disk is all. Works fine locally, but not on the travis builds.

Comment: I see. What does mv/cp results in? Could you link travis.yml?